# How to write a calculated field in Tableau which counts the number of products whose price tags are missing (null) and whose price <> $99?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I tried to write it using ISNULL but I'm getting error.

Comment: `where price is null or price <> 99`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ZN([Price])!=99
```

Wrap this in INT() to sum the result.